# Finding sum of geometric series $\sum\limits_{k=5}^ \infty \left(\frac{e}{\pi}\right)^{k-1} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

Determine the sum of the following geometric series.

I got confused here because I'm used to starting with $k=1$ and now suddenly it's $k=5$. Is there any difference?

$$\sum_{k=5}^ \infty   \left(\frac{e}{\pi}\right)^{k-1} $$

Comment: Just assume that the sum starts at $1$, determine the solution and then subtract the sum from $1$ to $4$ from the result. Du you understand what I mean?

Comment: determine the solution, yes got it, subtract sum from 1 to 4, didn't get it, could you be more specific

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k = \sum_{k=1}^4 a_k + \sum_{k=5}^\infty a_k$

Comment: @Teeban: Look at the hint from Nicholas Stull.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the geometric series 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }x^k=\frac{1}{1-x} \quad{|x|<1}$$
so
$$\sum_{k=5}^ \infty   (\frac{e}{\pi})^{k-1}=\sum_{k=0}^ \infty   (\frac{e}{\pi})^{k+4}=(\frac{e}{\pi})^4\sum_{k=0}^ \infty   (\frac{e}{\pi})^{k}=(\frac{e}{\pi})^4\frac{1}{1-\frac{e}{\pi}}$$

Comment: How , Can you explain please

Comment: Maybe get rid of the phony = signs?

Comment: $$\sum_{k=1}^ \infty   ar^{k-1}$$ is the formula for sum, if k=0 how can i find the sum

Comment: can you correct your post please?

Comment: done the correction

Comment: Your post (and that of the answer) both need corrected. The sum is an operator, so it doesn't equal anything. $\sum_{k=1}^\infty ar^{n-1} = \frac{a}{1-r}$, for $|r|<1$, but $\sum_{k=1}^\infty$ is meaningless without indicating what it is that you are adding up in the infinite series.

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^ \infty  = (\frac{e}{\pi})^{k+4}$ should be $\sum_{k=0}^ \infty (\frac{e}{\pi})^{k+4}$

Comment: @NicholasStull Yeah, I'm thinking it is just a typo

Comment: @NicholasStull thanks......

Comment: @ArianaGrande, I agree. Although I'm not 100% sure OP fully grasps the distinction. (OP Being @Teeban), so that comment is more for OP's benefit.

Comment: @NicholasStull oh and it is sum from 0 to $\infty$

Comment: @ArianaGrande, not as written. Although, there is a typo...That $n$ should be a $k$...(that's what I get for typing a comment in a hurry)

Comment: @NicholasStull I always have those typos, i normally just delete and retype to correct it. There should be a way to edit comments

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\sum_{k=a}^\infty f(k) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty f(k) - \sum_{k=1}^{a-1}f(k)$$
or more generally if $a < b < c$
$$\sum_{k=b}^c f(k) = \sum_{k=a}^c f(k) - \sum_{k=a}^{b-1}f(k)$$